# Xcode 8 - How To Disable Auto Adjustment Of Views When Deleting a Constraint In Storyboard

Tags: xcode

Before when I delete a constraint that sits between two views, the position or size of the two views doesn't get affected(meaning they don't automatically adjust itself in the storyboard). But now it does. An example would be let's we have two UIButtons aligned horizontally. I set the height and width of one equal to the other. Then if I delete one button, the other button will change it's size in the interface builder.

Is there a way to disable the auto adjusting of sizes and position of views when their constraint changes?